# Use jquery to select only the next one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help to figure it out. 
I've got a button radio, when this button is checked, the box just next to him have to change the id (YES ID not class, absolutely need it to be an ID)

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="contenance" />
 </td>
 <td><a href="">A super link</a>
 </td>
 <td>                       
    <input type="number" name="qty" class="text" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="contenance" />
 </td>
 <td><a href="">A super 2nd link</a>
 </td>
 <td>                       
    <input type="number" name="qty" class="text" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
 </td>
</tr>
</tr>
```

BUT with the script I've written, it apply the ID to all number box, while I just want the only one next to the button radio

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){

    $("input[type='number']").attr('id', 'quantity_wanted');

});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/micheler/y4jrotkc/4/

Comment: _“absolutely need it to be an ID”_ – I doubt that. You seem to be storing a quantity value there – and for that, a _custom data attribute_ would be much more appropriate than the id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all id must be unique. I sugest to use class instead. I create this to change id of input if radio is check:

```js
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
  //remove all id from input number
  $('input[type=number]').removeAttr('id');
  //check if radio is checked and apply id to input number next to it
  if($(this).prop("checked"))
    $(this).next().attr('id', 'quantity_wanted')
});
```

```css
#quantity_wanted {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page_navigation1">next</div>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
<p>
  <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="contenance" />
  <input type="number" id="" name="qty" class="text" size="2" maxlength="3" />
</p>
<p>
  <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="contenance" />
  <input type="number" name="qty" class="text" size="2" maxlength="3" />
</p>
```

Comment: Great answer! You just beat me.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've updated my code, because it's not quite what I needed. Your script change only the ID of the very next element

Comment: Ok check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/vk1haoc3/1/). You post different html structure from your OP..